# Определение USB-флэш в linux ubuntu средствами Qt на C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

Стоит задача: скопировать файлы с ftp-сервера на съемный носитель. Сделать это нужно средствами моего приложения, никакие другие программы и средства системы пользователь использовать не может (таково требование к разрабатываемому изделию). При вызове функции копирования пользователь в качестве возможных мест назначения должен увидеть только подключенные USB-флэш. Подскажите пожалуйста, как программными средствами из приложения на С++ (разработка в Qt) можно определить подключенные флэшки и вывести пользователю их список, с последующим просмотром папок на флэш для выбора папки назначения?

Comment: `QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo, QDir...`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin, Если правильно понял, QDir мне может выдать список всех примонтированых устройств. Как определить ,какие из них являются USB-флэш? А вот чем может помочь QSerialPort я не понял. Может поясните?

Comment: Если вам надо читать/писать в USB как в RS232 для этого нужен QSerialPort

Comment: @AlexanderChernin на данный момент мне нужно только обнаружить подключенные флэшки и исключить жесткий диск из мест назначения при копировании.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <libudev.h>
#include <mntent.h>
```

Перечисляем все блочные устройства, подключенные через USB

```
QList<udev_device*> listDevices()
{
    struct udev_enumerate *enu = ::udev_enumerate_new(m_udev);
    struct udev_list_entry *cur;
    ::udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem(enu, "block");
    ::udev_enumerate_add_match_property(enu, "ID_BUS", "usb");
    QList<udev_device*> list;

    ::udev_enumerate_scan_devices(enu);
    udev_list_entry_foreach(cur, ::udev_enumerate_get_list_entry(enu)) {
        struct udev_device* device = ::udev_device_new_from_syspath(m_udev, ::udev_list_entry_get_name(cur));
        if(device != Q_NULLPTR) {
        // для определения точки монтирования (/dev/sdb, /dev/sdb1, ...)
            // const auto* devname = ::udev_device_get_property_value(device, "DEVNAME");
            list << device;
        }
    }
    ::udev_enumerate_unref(enu);
    return list;
}
```

Ищем точку монтирования (если флешка примонтирована конечно)

```
QStringList mountPoints(const char* devname)
{
    struct mntent *ent;
    FILE *aFile;
    QStringList mountPoints;
    aFile = ::setmntent("/proc/mounts", "r");
    if (aFile == Q_NULLPTR ) {
        qCritical() << "Ошибка";
        return QStringList{};
    }
    while (Q_NULLPTR != (ent = ::getmntent(aFile))) {
        if(::strcmp(qPrintable(devname), ent->mnt_fsname) == 0) {
            mountPoints << ent->mnt_dir;
        }
    }
    ::endmntent(aFile);
    return mountPoints;
}
```

Comment: На системе, где нет `udev`, не заработает.